# Why does 'quickly package' fail with "An error has occurred when creating debian packaging"?

Tags: package-management, quickly

I've got a big problem with packing my quickly application for the Ubuntu App Showdown.
When I try to package or submit my application, I get some warnings:

```
quickly package --verbose
........
----------------------------------
WARNING: syntax errors in facebook/FacebookWindow.py: encoding declaration in
Unicode string (FacebookWindow.py, line 0)
WARNING: the following files are not recognized by DistUtilsExtra.auto:
  AUTHORS~
  facebook/AboutFacebookDialog.py~
  facebook/FacebookWindow.py~
  facebook/PreferencesFacebookDialog.py~
  facebook/__init__.py~
  facebook_lib/AboutDialog.py~
  facebook_lib/Builder.py~
  facebook_lib/PreferencesDialog.py~
  facebook_lib/Window.py~
  facebook_lib/__init__.py~
  facebook_lib/facebookconfig.py~
  facebook_lib/helpers.py~
  setup.py~
----------------------------------
An error has occurred when creating debian packaging
ERROR: can't create or update ubuntu package
ERROR: package command failed
Aborting
```

What does the second warning mean? How do I solve those warnings? I want to submit my app to the Ubuntu App developer Showdown into my PPA and it doesn't work.

Thanks for any answer.

Comment: Please post the output of `quickly package --verbose` when you are asking for support.

Comment: This was the output of 'quickly package --verbose'!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are probably using a version of the **python-distutils-extra** package from the *precise-proposed* pocket in the archive, that is newer than the stable release and that it is [known to cause trouble with the latest Quickly version](https://bugs.launchpad.net/quickly/+bug/1021969).

Try to downgrade it by running the following command, and then re-run the Quickly packaging command:

```
sudo apt-get install python-distutils-extra=2.32-2
```

Answer (score -1):

To get rid of the warnings, just delete all the files that are ending in "~". Those are back-up files created by your text editor whenever you save a file. It is safe to remove them if your app runs flawlessly when you do `quickly run` for example. The files ending in "~" are hidden files, so when you are in Nautilus, don't forget to hit Ctrl+H to see them.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem, the output of quickly package --verbose was:

```
running install_egg_info
Writing /tmp/tmpzO_6QQ/dockremoteclient-0.9.egg-info
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/python-mkdebian", line 368, in <module>
    egg = get_egg_info()
  File "/usr/bin/python-mkdebian", line 35, in get_egg_info
    k, v = l.strip().split(': ', 1)
ValueError: need more than 1 value to unpack
An error has occurred when creating debian packaging
ERROR: can't create or update ubuntu package
```

The problem was that in the setup.py file I had written a long_description with a new line (\n), [which is not good](https://askubuntu.com/questions/175224/quickly-setup-py-long-description-how-to-make-them-generate-a-multi-paragrap).
I removed it and the problem was solved.