# All special dependencies are lost when I do "quickly share" or "quickly  package"

Tags: application-development, compiling, quickly, dependencies

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why does 'quickly package' fail with “An error has occurred when creating debian packaging”?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/161124/why-does-quickly-package-fail-with-an-error-has-occurred-when-creating-debian)

I am developing an app using Quickly and it has a few dependencies like 'python-xdg' for example.

When I do `quickly share` on a computer that has Ubuntu 12.04 without Pre-released updates (precise-proposed), those dependencies are well reflected in `./debian/control`. But when I launch this command from an Ubuntu 12.04 with Pre-released updates (precise-proposed), not only do I get a lot of warnings (such as `WARNING: syntax errors in myapp_lib/__init.py__.py: encoding declaration in Unicode string`), but also `./debian/control` looses all sorts of special dependencies.

What should I do to solve this problem (preferably before the end of the Ubuntu App Showdown)?
The same happens for `quickly package`.

Comment: `proposed` is not included in PPA dependencies by default, FYI.

Comment: I don't want to include `proposed` in the dependencies, but 'python-xdg'. I activated proposed because of http://askubuntu.com/questions/156339/launchpad-failed-to-build-after-quickly-submitubuntu/157432#157432.

Comment: It's a giant mess. If I were you I'd skip the `submitubuntu` part, and after making final modifications to the control file, package it manually with `debuild -s` and `dput` it manually to a PPA. Sorry :/

Comment: It is not a duplicate because I am talking about a python package which used to be correctly and automatically added to debian/control with a previous version of Quickly.

Comment: Agreed, **not a duplicate**, please do not vote/flag to close.