# Debuild does not recognise some files

Tags: application-development, ppa

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why does 'quickly package' fail with “An error has occurred when creating debian packaging”?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/161124/why-does-quickly-package-fail-with-an-error-has-occurred-when-creating-debian)

I have submitted an app for the Ubuntu App Showdown and had a response with some code to merge. The changes were all in the /debian folder which automatically gets updated when I -run `quickly submitubuntu`. This means that I have to update my PPA manually, so based on the advice of [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/163096/how-do-i-apply-the-fixes-suggested-from-the-app-review-board-to-my-app) I ran `debuild -S` part of the output is the following:

```
WARNING: the following files are not recognized by DistUtilsExtra.auto:
  help/C/figures/icon.png
  help/C/index.page
  help/C/preferences.page
  help/C/topic1.page
  po/tripplanner.pot
  tripplanner.desktop.in
```

What does this mean? Does this mean that these files won't be included if I upload the changes file to my PPA?

Or is there a way that I can update quickly to use the 'correct' files in the /debian folder?